# Cannot update project from its SVN repo in Xcode

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I have a project that lives in an SVN repository. The repository is added to Xcode, I can browse it from my Organizer and check out projects. Here's the problem. Whenever I'm trying to *update* an old version of the project to a new one, I right-click on the project int the Project Navigator and go to Source Control -> Update selected files, I get the following error:

> **The operation could not be performed because the selection is invalid.**
>
> Please verify the selection and try again.

What am I doing wrong? I tried selecting individual files instead of the project, and I tried selected lines of code (silly, but you never know). Am I not checking out the project correctly? Is this a common issue?

Cheers! = )

Comment: Id there any special character in the path of the project? Some kind of encoding issue?

Comment: @VonC No, there should be none.

Comment: I have this issue as well, and it's confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: @mikek I started using external SVN tools, not Xcode. Never actually figured it out.

Comment: I'm amazed that support in XCode for SVN is so poor. I'm trying to get Git to work at the moment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and map Update All and Commit All to some keys, when you use those options (no update/commit specific file but ALL project) you shoudn't see those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wasn't done properly in the past and from then on the system cannot manage it anymore correctly.

I would have backuped the probject and then delete the project entire directry, and than checkout the project from scratch using the organizer.